# Salesforce webservice to get username and token from DB by hitting php class

Tags: php, database, web-services, salesforce

Till now i am able to get data from DB into salesforce by making a request to phpscript from Salesforce.That means Queries are wriiten in php classes.So We are saving server password in Apex class while making data request. But my problem is that i want to make it more secure by not saving password on salesforce side.So could you please help me to write an apex class which will hit phpscript to get an encrypted token.